# Crystal reporting, subreporting flow, multiple columns orientation

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

We have a report in Crystal Reports. On that report there is a general header on every page and  after that we have multiple items. Currently the items are displayed from left to right and when fillend it goes to the second line. So it looks like this:

```
HEADER
A   B
C   D
E   F
```

What we want is first fill the first column and then fill the second column so it shows like

```
HEADER
A  D
B  E
C  F
```

Is this possible?

Regards
Patrick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the following pics. It suppose to solve your question. Through the section expert, select the "Details" section and tick "Format with multiple columns". A new tab appears - "Layout" and there you can configure your columns as you see fit. 
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]